# DataTables, reloading of dataset after Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

How do I load DataTables with new date, based on a datepicker selection.

Data is loaded using client side Ajax calls, and then I want to create a new dataset based on a date range.

Whenever, I call my function to reload the data, I get initialisation errors. I've tried to destroy the table, and the draw it again, but nothing.

Ajax call:

```
   var getMessageDate = function () {

   var tdata;

      console.log(fromDateSelection);

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "DataTable.aspx/GetSummary",
         data: JSON.stringify({ "sender": $('#ddBICS :selected').val(), "date": $('#fromDateSelection') }),
         dataType: "json",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         success: function(result) {

         tdata = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);

         oMessageDate = $("#tblDataTable").DataTable({
            data: tdata,
        });
    }
  });
}
```

then the select date change event is:

```
  $('#fromDate').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    orientation: "auto left",
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
   }).on('change', function () {

   getMessageDate();
   fromDateSelection = $('#fromDate').val();
 });
```

How can I achieve rebuilding the DataTable after the selection of a date?

Comment: basically you want to erase the old data and put new data with out destroying the table?

Comment: Yes, if possible. I'm upgrading from version 1.9 to use version 1.10. Previously, I used server side processing, so didnt come across this before now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
var datatableObj = $("#tblDataTable").DataTable(); // In global scope
```

To remove all rows

```
datatableObj.clear() // to clear the existing data. Remember this will not redraw the empty table. to redraw, append .draw() with .clear()
```

To add

```
datatableObj.rows.add([ {
    "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
    "position":   "System Architect",
    "salary":     "$3,120",
    "start_date": "2011/04/25",
    "office":     "Edinburgh",
    "extn":       "5421"
}, {
    "name": "Garrett Winters",
    "position": "Director",
    "salary": "$5,300",
    "start_date": "2011/07/25",
    "office": "Edinburgh",
    "extn": "8422"
} ] )
.draw(); // Use add function of rows object to add multiple tr. and finally draw the datatable
```

Check the [docs](http://datatables.net/reference/api/) for more info

**UPDATE**

Use the below code

```
var oMessageDate = $("#tblDataTable").DataTable(); 

var getMessageDate = function () {

   var tdata;

    console.log(fromDateSelection);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "DataTable.aspx/GetSummary",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "sender": $('#ddBICS :selected').val(), "date": $('#fromDateSelection') }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(result) {
            tdata = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);
            oMessageDate.clear().rows.add(tdata).draw();
        }
    });
}
```

Also, i think `fromDateSelection = $('#fromDate').val();` should come before `getMessageDate()`

Comment: Ok, so, I'm not looking to add additional rows. My date range, basically needs to make a call to the database, and retrieve a whole new dataset. So, first off, the table is loaded with all values that match today. After changing the date, i need to return more / or less depening on dates seleted.

Comment: Plus, I am already using a global scope variable, oMessageDate

Comment: post the response structure

Comment: i asked about the structure. if the data is in array of objects format then you can use like `oMessageDate.rows.add(tdata).draw()`

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad:

{
    "d": "[{\"MessageReference\":\"VALUE\",\"Beneficiary\":\"NAME Taylor\",\"Currency\":\"EUR\",\"Amount\":14536631.27,\"MessageDate\":\"29/08/2014 13:47:25\",\"Status\":\"Hit released\",\"MessageId\":\"1\"}]"
}

Comment: I think looking at your response, I may need to move the initialisation and loading of data in separate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution with [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) :

```
$('table.datatable').DataTable({
    // ...
    "drawCallback": function (settings) {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker('remove');
    }
});
```